# mongoengine.errors.LookUpError: Cannot resolve field "$question_title"

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

Am working on a django project using mongodb's mongoengine. I want to create a text index on my models, This is what i have

`models.py`

```
from mongoengine import *

class Questions(Document):
     question_title = StringField(max_length=100)
     question_text = StringField(max_length=500, required=True)
     authors = ReferenceField(Users, required=True,    reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
     creation_date = DateTimeField()
     votes = IntField(default=0)

    #.. more fields definitions

   meta = {
        'indexes' : [
        {
            'fields' : ['$question_title', '$question_text'],
            'default_language' : 'english',
            'weight' : {
                '$question_title': 10,
                '$question_text' : 5
            }
        }
    ]
   }
```

But then django raises that error. What am i supposed to do to create text indexes in my documents. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the index definition ([examples here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/text-indexes.html#defining-a-document-with-text-index)) there are some errors: `weights` instead of `weight`, than remove the `$` from the weights keys:

```
    meta = {
        'indexes' : [
        {
            'fields' : ['$question_title', '$question_text'],
            'default_language' : 'english',
            'weights' : {
                'question_title': 10,
                'question_text' : 5
            }
        }
    ]
   }
```